# Angular ng-if doesnt recompile directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

As I know, ng-if recreates directive by compiled state of it. But if I have if/else condition in directive code that influences to compiled HTML,

How can I recompile directive on ng-if's expression changed? Because compiling is doing after refreshing a page. If I refresh a page and get one compiled state and after (without refreshing page) change logged flag, that there in ng-if expression, compiled state must be other, but It's not.

For example:

```
<directive-one ng-if="logged"></directive-one>
```

I have 2 variants of compiled state of this directive: have cart items and haven't (empty table).

If I refresh page and was be logged - all are nice. If I logout - directive destroy, If I login again - directive will recreates again with logged compiled state.

But if I refresh page and was be logouted - compiled state everytime I loging or logout will be "haven't cart items". Because the compiled state at moment on refreshing the page was "haven't cart items"...

Directive code: http://pastebin.com/KpCHwpcc

Comment: Are you changing the value of $scope.logged outside a "$$phase" (digest)? If so, call $scope.$apply(); after changing the value of $scope.logged.

Comment: @marvin in my code it's "$rootScope.logged" and it changing from a angular service (AuthService, that provide all login/logout functional).

Comment: rootScope is the parent scope of all, with prototype inheritance you'll end up having logged being a property on rootScope, but your template binds to the scope of the directive (if the directive isn't transparent which i assume here). 
The change happens on $rootScope.logged, The watch happens on "someinherititedscope.logged". Changing $rootScope.logged will not fire the "someinheritedscope.logged". 2 different "logged" properties.

Comment: Why the watch happens on "someinherititedscope.logged" if I put "$rootScope.logged" to ng-if expression? Dont understand. In expression there isn't just "logged", and "$rootScope.logged".

Comment: Can you provide the directive code ?

Comment: @BiAiB I added link to directive's code pastebin into post

Comment: As you can see in directive's code "IF" condition that influences to cart_items (if $rootScope.logged == true - cart_items are filled by data, and if $rootScope.logged == false - cart_items are stay empty. That is two different compiled state a told.

Comment: Why do you use compile ? This will be done automatically here (unless you specify terminal:true).

Comment: @BiAiB I removed it already :) its not the point

Comment: Your directive compilation happens once, that's where the .logged check is done. if you want the template to change based on the rootscope.logged, you'll have to move the check inside the template. e.g. data-ng-if="$rootScope.logged" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Moving the directive from element to attribute fixed this.

```
<directive-one ng-if="logged"></directive-one>
```

refactor to this:

```
<div data-directive-one ng-if="logged"></div>
```

(don't forget to change the required in the directive form E to A)

The priority on the element for directives should work there properly.

Comment: No, it doesn't work :(
Still after refreshing the page when I was logouted, compiled state staying "haven't cart items' after log in.

Comment: I think the problem is, that the directive code won't be recompiled completely. The link method should be recompiled all the time. Maybe you move the data fetching stuff into the link method.